# Update query with arrayFilters

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, array-filter

I have the sample Document:

```
{
    "customerId" : 503,
    "rule" : {
        "firewallRules" : [
            {
                "action" : "Allow",
                "timestamp" : 1626426777759,
                "from" : {
                    "group" : "group1"
                },
                "to" : {
                    "group" : "group2"
                }
            },
            {
                "action" : "Allow",
                "timestamp" : 1626426777760,
                "from" : {
                    "group" : "group2"
                },
                "to" : {
                    "group" : "group1"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to update the `"rule. firewallRules.action":"Deny"` when the `"customerId":503`, `"rule. firewallRules.from.group":"group1"` and `"rule. firewallRules.to.group":"group2"` matches

The following query I'm trying with `arrayFilters`:

```
db.intcodepolicygroup.update(
    {
        "customerId":503,
    },
    {
        $set:{
            "rule.firewallRules.$[fwall].action": "Deny"
        }
    },
    {
        arrayFilters:[
            {
                "fwall.from.group":"group1",
                "fwall.to.group":"group2",
            }
        ]
    }
)
```

But it is sending the following response:

`WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 0, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })`

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: your query looks good, see working [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/W-cnkAt15X1)

Comment: Oops, there was a typo :D my bad 
Thanks, @turivishal I have been debugging this for ages.